# SQL - concatenation and iteration

Tags: sql-server

Wanted to know if there is a way of iterating and concatenating a string in SQL to a new column every cycle in a while loop.

```
set nocount on

declare @rowcount INT,
    @BL_A VARCHAR(MAX)
 set @rowcount =2


while @rowcount <=12
begin
    set @BL_A = '[DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[Col_'+CAST(@rowcount as varchar(MAX))+']'
    print @BL_A

    update [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
    set @BL_A = [DB2].[dbo].[Table2].[Y_Value]
    from [DB2].[dbo].[Table2]
    where [DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[X_Value] = [DB2].[dbo].[Table2].[X_Value];

    set @rowcount= @rowcount+1
end
print 'End of Script'
```

The query runs without errors and prints off this, but doesn't update the columns

```
[DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[Col_2]
[DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[Col_3]
....
[DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[Col_12]
End of Script
```

Comment: You should try `[DB2].[dbo].[Table2].[Y_Value] = @BL_A` instead

Comment: You can't set a value to a column. Only a column to a value in this case. FYI I'm using _Microsoft SQL 2008_

Comment: Ok, your code doesn't makes sense either way...can you elaborate in what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create the *dynamic query* to update the table, try like below:

```
exec ('update [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
    set '+@BL_A+' = [DB2].[dbo].[Table2].[Y_Value]
    from [DB2].[dbo].[Table2]
    where [DB1].[dbo].[Table1].[X_Value] = [DB2].[dbo].[Table2].[X_Value];')
```

HTH!

Comment: You're a wizard. Weird how something so simple worked. Thanks!